# Expand constants in IntelliJ quick documentation

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

Eclipse has a nice feature which expands `String` constants passed to an annotation when hovering above the annotated element:

[image]

Is there a way of doing the same in IntelliJ's quick documentation?

Comment: I do not this there is a built-in feature for this. Feel free to [file a request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

Comment: I wonder what is a use case of concatenating strings in the annotation?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I'm using owner (http://owner.aeonbits.org/) for configuration. The configuration keys in the interfaces (i.e. `@Key` annotations) are in a hierarchy - "component1.subcomponent2.confValue3".